# Updating localStorage based on result of window onbeforeunload confirmation?

Tags: javascript

I have a chat window, and I need to track when it is closed. Also, I'd like to have a confirmation dialog when the user attempts to close. My code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (window.confirm("Do you really want to leave?")) { 
        localStorage.setItem('chatOpen', false); // OK was clicked
    } // else do nothing (remain on page)
};
```

The 'if' logic seems to work, but my issue is that the window still closes when the user clicks the 'Cancel' button (IE10).

Comment: Ok, and where is the part of your code that should prevent this?

Comment: you need to tell the window not to close via your event handler, but you can simply use `onunload` instead, which will fire when it should for the task described.